# Bit Array - All possible combinations

Tags: ruby

I have array of 0's and 1's.  And I need a function which return 'next' array. Something like this:

```
f([0,0,0,0]) -> [0,0,0,1]
f([0,0,0,1]) -> [0,0,1,0]
f([0,1,1,1]) -> [1,0,0,0]
```

Is there any library function or do I need to coding it myself ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby includes a simple way to convert between binary and base 10.

```
"0010".to_i(2)
=> 2

13.to_s(2)
=> "1101"
```

So a simple way to do what you need is

```
def f(a)
  (a.join.to_i(2) + 1).to_s(2).split("").map{ |v| v.to_i }
end
```

Here is a way to add two nbit numbers.

```
def nbit_addition(a, b)
  bit1 = toBits(a)
  bit2 = toBits(b)
  bitLength = bit1.length > bit2.length ? bit1.length : bit2.length
  bit3 = []
  for i in 0...bitLength
    bit1[i] = 0 if bit1[i].nil? 
    bit2[i] = 0 if bit2[i].nil? 
    bit3[i] = 0 if bit3[i].nil?
    bit3[i] += (bit1[i] + bit2[i])
    if bit3[i] > 1 
      bit3[i + 1] = 0 if bit3[i + 1].nil?
      bit3[i] %= 2
      bit3[i + 1] += 1
    end 
  end 
  bit3.join.to_s.reverse.to_i(2)
end 

def toBits(value)
  bit = []
  value.to_s(2).reverse.split(//).each { |b| bit << b.to_i } 
  return bit 
end
```

Comment: Nice trick with the `to_i(2)`. Didn't know that.

Comment: Fixed a mistake that it returned an array with a string. Should work now.

Comment: Simple solution doesn't work. f(Array.new(16, 0) returns [1]

Comment: You need to add '1' before your code.  Something like:  a.insert(0, 1)   a = (a.join.to_i(2) + 1).to_s(2).split("").map{ |v| v.to_i } a.shift

Comment: Demas, shouldn't it return [1]? 0000 is 0 in and the next value is 0001 which is equivalent to 1? Do you want it to have the first zeros too? I didn't quiet understand your second comment. Feel free to edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, it was in my answer f([0,0,0,0]) -> [0,0,0,1].  But anyway thanks for your idea. It helps me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to generate all possible combinations (as the title says), well they are actually permutations (with repetition).

```
f = [0,1].repeated_permutation(4)
16.times {p f.next}
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 1]
[1, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 0, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straightforward to convert between an array of bits into a number:

```
[0,1,1,1].inject(0) { |number,bit| number * 2 + bit }
 => 7
```

It's of course easy to get the next number:

```
7.succ
 => 8
```

...and it's easy to turn that back into a bit array:

```
8.to_s(2).chars.map(&:to_i)
 => [1, 0, 0, 0]
```

That said, if you have to do this, you should probably re-think why you have an array of bits in the first place. `8` is a much more sensible representation for a number than `[1, 0, 0, 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Array
  def binary_succ(lindex=nil)
    lindex ||= size - 1    
    if lindex >= 0
      if self[lindex] == 0 then self[lindex] = 1
      else self[lindex] = 0; binary_succ(lindex-1) end
    end
    self
  end
end

[0,1,1,1].binary_succ #=> [1,0,0,0]
```

Comment: `[0,1,1,1].join.succ.split(//).map(&:to_i)` yields `[0, 1, 1, 2]`, which is wrong.

Comment: @willglynn, you're right, fixed

Answer (score 0):

I was bored, so here's a solution that doesn't involve stringifying the array

```
def succ arr
  overflow = false
  rev = arr.reverse
  rev[0] += 1
  rev.map do |el|
    el += 1 if overflow
    case el
    when 0, 1
      overflow = false
      el
    when 2
      overflow = true
      0
    end
  end.reverse
end

succ [0,0,0,0] # => [0, 0, 0, 1]
succ [0,0,0,1] # => [0, 0, 1, 0]
succ [0,1,1,1] # => [1, 0, 0, 0]
```